# Struggling with json_decode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have looked at many posts on this forum and still having problems, can't get my head round it.

i am retreiving a php page through ajax which is posting a json object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    data: sendData,
    type: "POST",
    error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){
    // Work out what the error was and display the appropriate message
    },
    success: function(data){
    // data retrived ok
    var myData = data;
        // do something with data
    }
});
```

my json is like this (generated with js):

```
{"borough": {"id": "3"}, "cat":{"id": "5", "id": "47", "id": "98"}}
```

using firebug i have hecked and its getting passed across

my problem is with the php, i cant seem to get the data json_decoded.

```
<?php
    $catPost = $_POST['cat'];
    echo($catPost);
    $catData = json_decode($catPost, true);
    var_dump($catData);
?>
```

the echo statement prints out [object Object]

but the var_dump prints out null

what am i doing wrong? how do i access the diffirent "id" values in the data????

any help greatly appreciated.

the test page can be seen at [http://http://www.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/NEW Search/fullsearch_jq.php](http://www.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/NEW%20Search/fullsearch_jq.php)

Instructions for testing:
(use thetext "Advanced search" under the select category dropdown to perform the ajax call
also select a borough and somecategories topopulate the json object with some data

EDIT:

the json is created by the following script which reads values of selected tages from an array:

```
var sendData = {"borough":[], "cat":[]};
//alert('borough tagger add '+BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]);
sendData.borough.push({"id":BoroughTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]});
$.each(CatTagger.myIdArray, function(intIndex, objValue) {
    alert('cat Tagger add '+CatTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]);
    sendData.cat.push({"id":CatTagger.myIdArray[intIndex]});
});
```

which would create a json object like the following: (checked this in fiebug)

```
{"borough": {"id": "3"}, "cat":{"id": "5", "id": "47", "id": "98"}}
```

I am now using `stringData = JSON.stringify(sendData)` to send the data via ajax
but there dosent seem to be any name in the post collections, the string is there but if i reference it using `$myData = $_POST;` which echos "ArrayArray"
the json_decode errors with: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\wamp\www\ReelFilm\NEW Search\getAdvSearch.php on line 7

so how do i get the ajax call to assign a name tothe sent sata so i can access it using `$_POST['myData']`

Comment: is it copy paste? {"id", "3"} it should be {"id": "3"} - colon not coma :) maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Do you encode it as a String or send directly the JSON object as-is in javascript ?

Comment: @tom tu, the json is actually generated by a script i typed that up, is using : willchange the question to reflect that

Comment: @Dizzy Bryan High: have you tried to stringify the JSON before sending? check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json the stringify method - though you might need external library for JSON to have it work on all browsers and different versions - this is my call for the problem. And try to echo your $_POST table on response - it might be that you are not getting what you'd expect without stringifying the JSON first

Comment: the echo($_POST); returns Array[object Object]

Comment: @Radoslav: its just sent as a json object, how would i encode that as a string?

Comment: @tom tu: ive tried stingifying the object which gets sent as a string, but what do i do with the string in php to convert it to something i can use??

Comment: then you have to decode the string on PHP that's what json_decode does end to have json object usable on backend side :) just make sure you capture the right element from the $_POST table

Comment: is strange there does nor seem to be any named values in the $_POST table just the string, although firebug says:Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded     
{"borough":[{"id":"5"}],"... 
JSON     borough     [Object { id="5"}]     cat      [Object { id="145"}, Object { id="103"}, Object { id="71"}]

Comment: have you tried to use json_decode on the received string?

Comment: yeah but that just errors aswell the sent string using json_decode when i have stringified it seems malformed to me: {"borough":[{"id":"5"}],{"cat" :[{"id":"5", "id":"78","id":"50"}]}} what are the extra [] for?

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\wamp\www\ReelFilm\NEW Search\getAdvSearch.php on line 7 thats what i get after using stringify

Answer (score 2):

If json_decode() gives you a null, use [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to try and identify the reason for the failure.

Comment: the json_lat_error(); returns nothing
echo of $_POST['cat'] - [object Object]

var_dump($catPost) - string '[object Object]' (length=15)

var_dump($catData) - null

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to your problem. Try this.

It may have been that as you are using jQuery, they may have posted it in a different way to cause PHP to recognize it as an object. I know you've done it in json_decode() but the echo() output only recognizes the variable as an object therefore you will need to force PHP to change it to array.

```
<?php
    $catPost = (array) $_POST['cat']; /* PHP may post it as an object, this converts to array, which you'll need to find the data from */
    echo($catPost);
    $catData = json_decode($catPost, true);
    var_dump($catData);
?>
```

If that doesn't work, base64_encode the jQuery ajax() data before pushing it to your server. You can find a base64_encode function at phpjs.org at [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode:457) and simply encode your string and then use PHP base64_decode() to decode the output and then json_encode().

Hope it helps!

Comment: get this error if i try that:
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\wamp\www\ReelFilm\NEW Search\getAdvSearch.php on line 7

Comment: Uh. What does the output say? Try my second solution and tell me what that's saying.

Comment: hmm dont understand how to use the script you directed me too.
i look in firbug and the json object seems to be ok

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this option to your ajax-call:

```
traditional:false
```

looks like  somehow the traditional-option of ajaxSetup is set to true(if it is , there will no recursive serialization be done on passed objects)

Comment: I think it's time to make a decision what you like to send. Right now you send the json as a string, what will have no effect as long as  the thing doesn't have a name, because you cant access it without a name out of the POST-array.